# Android GoogleMap follow my location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

All the basic stuff, I have a SupportMapFragment, everything works fine, I just need to know if there is a short way of making the map follow my position or do I have to move the camera every time the location changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly what you want, but you can use:

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

To add a button to your map at top right corner (Like in the native Google Maps application) that will allow the user change the camera position to his location when he wants.

Answer (score 4):

Well first of all thanks for your time Naskov but this is not a mapView, it's a MapFragment. the code I am using right now (in case someone needs it) is this (onUpdateLocation)

```
    if (mapFragment.theMap != null) {
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(getLocation().getLatitude(),
                        getLocation().getLongitude())).zoom(14.0f).build();
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
        mapFragment.theMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }
```

I was just wondering if there is some built in method for doing it, also because this doesnt go very smooth. If someone comes up with a better idea please post it

Comment: Use `animateCamera` instead. Also you can use built-in [GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setOnMyLocationChangeListener%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener%29) instead of directly working with `LocationManager`. And remember users will not like you if you force map to show their position when they want to see something else. ;)

Comment: You are right, never thought about the map's own listener. will try animateCamera later and keep it only if it makes things smoother, otherwise I dont think you need an animation for a small position update. And YES, this should be optional